# Storing temporary data (JAVA + GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am writing a multiplayer game where I allow players to attack each other. 
Only the attacker must be logged in.
I need to know how many attacks player did in last 6 hours, and I need to know if the defender was attacked during last 1 hour. I don't care about attacks done more than 6 hours ago. Is there any way to implement it better than storing these data in database and deleting "expired" data (older than 6 hours)?
Server is written in java, clients will be Android.
Any ideas / tutorial links or even keywords are appreciated. Also, if you think there is no better solution, please say so :)

Answer (score 0):

For GAE, there is no real alternative, no. Besides using the datastore, GAE offers a `memcache` system, which, in fact, is designated for storing temporary data. However, as stated in the documentation, "Values can expire from the memcache at any time, and may be expired prior to the expiration deadline set for the value." Therefore, it would be the best to use the datastore.

Comment: Yeah I saw the note that memcache can expire at any time, so I assumed that this is not a good way to store this data, I just thought maybe there is some other way to do it. Thanks for the reply.